# Why it must be use the await for save/get local data in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, local-storage

I want to save data to local(just a few data), and I find several package for do that (e.g shared_preferences,secure_storage,sqflite), but all of them are need to use await (Future), if I use these, I have to change my existing codes for wrap in Future, but I just feel that's very troublesome, so I am wondering why all of these are need to use await for save data? or can I use another easy way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` as the name suggest wait for some event without stopping following lines of code to execute because that work will take some milliseconds to perform. So, it's a good idea to use `await` which needs to have `async` in the function.

There is other way of doing this work without using `async-await`. 
That's `then()`.

So, you go with this without having to add `async` to your function.

```
performWork().then((result) {}));
```

Comment: How does this answer `Why it must be use the await for save/get local data in Flutter?`?

Comment: The question content also ask you is there a way to avoid async await. So this answers the body. Your answer answers title.

Comment: His content clearly ask why it's asynchronous. This is in comparison to Javascript for instance, where `LocalStorage` is synchronous

Comment: Did you read last line which says can I use another easy way to do that? Let OP decide whether my answer provides him solution or it is just irrelevant. Thanks :)

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, and my purpose that want to find another ways not just using await in these package, because I really don't want to change all of my codes! :)

Comment: this is indeed an issue for me. using then when saving data looksnlike a good workaround. but once you retrieve data is where you go back to square one since you cant do anything else after you get the value from storage. so youre still forced to change your code and place them inside the then()

Answer (score 5):

To be clear: It is impossible to have a synchronous system call in flutter.

This is due to an architectural decision: Instead of having the language bridge, Flutter uses two bus (one dart, one native) sending messages to each other.

This is faster than by using a bridge but enforce asynchronous messages.

Comment: Can you now undo downvoting my answer because OP found it relevant to the question asked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to use `await` you can call `then()` on the `Future` object. Refer this [link](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#the-future-api) for more details.

If you are working with Flutter you will definitely have to handle Future's there is no work around it.